# Calling a function inside document.ready from outside document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Jquery function defined as :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
function initAutoComplete(textBox, query, isMustMatch, isAjaxAfterKeyPress)
        {
           // autocomplete logic
        }

});
```

I am calling this function from outside document.ready as :

```
initAutoComplete($("#txt" + FromTo + "Country"), "WebAddr?srvList=Country&areaCd=OT&val=", true, false);
```

the initAutoComplete is not recognized which is correct as its inside the scope of document.ready().

I tried below code by hooking the function with `window` object :

```
window.initAutoComplete = function(textBox, query, isMustMatch, isAjaxAfterKeyPress)
        {  
            //autocomplete logic
        }
```

Now I called this function from outside document.ready as :

```
initAutoComplete($("#txt" + FromTo + "Country"), "WebAddr?srvList=Country&areaCd=OT&val=", true, false);
```

But I am unable to fix the reference error : initAutoComplete is not recognized.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why not declaring `initAutoComplete` outside of ready closure?

Comment: If using `window.initAutoComplete = ..` did not fix the error, then that line was not run *prior* to trying to calling `initAutoComplete`. The error is perfectly explainable, and is correct - so what tries to call what? Where *and* when are important.

Comment: when I am using initAutoComplete() outside document.ready(), the autocomplete() function in my autocomplete.js is not recognized.

Comment: Just define `function initAutoComplete() {...}` outside of the `.ready()` handler at the top level.  If you want it to be a global function so you can call it from anywhere, then just declare it as so and you can call it from anywhere without regarding to timing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this discussion

[window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

The order of events depends on the browser you are using. There is a subtle difference. Read through the article and make necessary changes if possible to "onload" rather than "ready".

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Changed reference to window to use the jQuery version as the vanilla version is not working.

When you define the function on the window like:

```
$(window).initAutoComplete = function(textBox, query, isMustMatch, isAjaxAfterKeyPress)
        {  
            //autocomplete logic
        }
```

Then you also need to call it on the window like so:

```
 $(window).initAutoComplete($("#txt" + FromTo + "Country"), "WebAddr?srvList=Country&areaCd=OT&val=", true, false);
```

The only other thing I would mention is to make sure that you calling it outside of the document.ready is in fact done after document.ready has fired.

Comment: Got the error : TypeError: window.initAutoComplete is not a function. I made sure that I am calling window.initAutoComplete when document.ready is fired.

Comment: Hmm Try using the jquery window object, that is how I've done this in the past, I will update the answer with this.

Comment: Sorry, but still the same error : TypeError: $(...).initAutoComplete is not a function.

Comment: Then It looks like the code calling it is in fact running before the code that defines it, perhaps look at Sesha's answer to see if that helps.